# How to move a promise through lamda?

Tags: c++, lambda, promise

I want to move a promise into a callback funtion `(onConcatenated)`.

The following is the currently properly working example.

```
void onConcatenated(void)
{
    std::cout << "Callback triggered " << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    // Let's subscribe for the 'concatenated' signals
    concatenatorProxy->uponSignal("concatenated").onInterface(interfaceName).call([](){ onConcatenated(void); });
    concatenatorProxy->finishRegistration();
.
.
}
```

What I have done so far is this

```
  void onConcatenated(std::promise<int> p)
  {
      std::cout << "Callback triggered " << std::endl;
      p.set_value(1);
  }
  std::promise<int> promise;
  std::future<int> future = promise.get_future();

  concatenatorProxy->uponSignal("concatenated").onInterface(interfaceName).call([](){ onConcatenated(std::move(promise)); });
```

But I run into `error: ‘promise’ is not captured` compile error.

What I want ultimately is to block the calling function until the callback triggers and does something like    `promise.set_value` to allow the calling function to proceed.

Comment: `[p = std::move(promise)]() mutable { onConcatenated(std::move(p)); }`